# Group by a column, in a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I group by `:key_id` using this query (`key_id` is a column in the report table), and that query is a method in a model called `Project`

```
self.reports.select{ |report| report.level <= 50}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't want to use select method with a block here. The reason is that this is a method defined on array, and hence is returning pure ruby array, not the relation object. Instead do:

```
self.reports.where('level <= ?', 50).group(:key_id)
```

Comment: I get this: `column "reports.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` - ` SELECT "reports".* FROM "reports"  WHERE "reports"."project_id" = $1 AND (level <= 50) GROUP BY key_id`

Comment: You will need to add select statement to above code to specify what you want to do with other columns when grouping - e.g. if you just want to count elements with same key_id you need to add 'select('key_id, count(*) as count')`

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
self.reports.select{ |report| report.level <= 50 }.group_by(&:key_id)
```

`.group_by(&:key_id)` is a concise way of saying `.group_by{ |report| report.key_id }`